# Most outsourced industries of USA?

Tags: international-trade, united-states

Which industries reduced the most in the USA as a result of outsourcing and imports?
Maybe textiles is one of them. I heard about a rust belt. Which ones are the others?

Comment: Reduced in what sense? Loss of employment? Over what time frame? Another issue is that “outsourcing” refers to replacing employees within a firm with workers elsewhere. It is very hard to determine the number of employees involved in a comprehensive fashion.

Comment: Yes by loss of employment. From outsourcing and trade deficit

Comment: You would need to have data from other countries on those jobs being replaced. I'm not sure you can easily get at that. The closest I can think of is work by Autor *et al* on cognitive vs manual and routine vs non-routine jobs... if you applied that to international data. Even then, concluding outsourcing had happened would be mere speculation.